# Unknown behaviour on Java Spring Boot Framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, deployment

Can anyone explain to me, why **Spring Boot** is sending me an login-form as default http responde when accessing the specified context-path:

```
# configuring Tomcat Server Host
server.address = 127.0.0.1
server.tomcat.threads.max = 20
server.servlet.context-path=/webapp
```

I am accessing this site by typing: **http://127.0.0.1:8080/webapp**

My File structure looks like this:

```
|-.idea
|-.mvn
|-src
   |-java
   |-resources
   |-webapp
      |-resources
      |-script
      |-styles
      |-index.html
```

I expected, that as default, when defining the context-path, the **index.html**-file would be sent back as response. Instead I receive a login-form, which wasn't designed by myself.

Comment: did you add security library and enable it?

Comment: Let me guess you have `spring-boot-starter-security` as a dependency.

Comment: Well, this may explain why i got this request, but do you also know, how i can configure username and password for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
|-.idea
|-.mvn
|-src
   |-java
   |-resources
       |-static
         |-resources
         |-script
         |-styles
         |-index.html
```

You can use static folder to publish index html if you didn't enable security.
If you enabled the security layer then you have to configure it.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CustomWebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final UserService userService;
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().cors().and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, ChallengeConstant.AUTHORIZE_ENDPOINT).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, ChallengeConstant.TOKEN_ENDPOINT).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/*").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/assets/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(new JWTFilter(userService, objectMapper), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
}
```

Here is an example of configuration.

Below two lines will skip auth flows for index html and asset folder.

```
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/*").permitAll()
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/assets/**").permitAll()
```

Comment: Makes sense, but when i need it, i have to configure it, also in the ```application.properties```-file, right?

Comment: I have updated answer with example of configuration

Comment: you don't need to use JWT filter ofcourse

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot Security Library automatically add login form, and provide password in console for username - 'user'. This is default behavior of spring security.
If you want to configure your username and password that you need to,

- Create configurer class which will extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`  of Spring security. then:
- Override it's `configure` method and provide your username, password in it either In-memory or from DB.
  https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-security/